# Error Migrating Spring boot 1.5.10 to 2.0.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate spring boot application from Spring Boot version 1.5.10 to 2.0.6. My application was working fine with Spring Boot 1.5.10. But when i change it to 2.0.6, I am unable to start my application. I get below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;
    at com.trng.pcf02.Pcf02Application.main(Pcf02Application.java:15)
```

I am using Gradle 4.5 and Intellij IDEA as my IDE.

And here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


ext {
    springCloudServicesVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.SR1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

My Main class is as below

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Pcf02Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Pcf02Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please post your gradle file?

Comment: Posted my gradle file.

Comment: Can you also post your `main` method?

Comment: I have posted main class code too.

Comment: Looks like it is still trying to access `run(Object, String[])` [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-). Can you confirm with the build output which version of Spring Boot is being used?

Comment: I don't see the `implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')` in the dependencies section of the `build.gradle`.

Comment: Thanks All!!!. It works the problem was with class files. Class files were generated using Spring boot 1.5. When i changed to 2.0.6 the class was not recompiled. So I have to delete my build and out folder, and it worked.