# Spring Boot Application error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Why i'm getting this error while running simple SpringBoot Application.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext;
>     at
>   io.javabrain.springbootstarter.CourseApiApp.main(CourseApiApp.java:10)

```
package io.javabrain.springbootstarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CourseApiApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CourseApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

It should be running successfully

Comment: How did you create your application? The file structure is incorrect probably.

Comment: could you post your maven pom.xml file ?

Comment: That looks like a mismatch version. Are you using same version for building and running it? Check your dependencies.

Comment: This seems to be build issue. Build the project again with `clean install`. Then do update project. Then try to start the project

Comment: I have many similar classes in my projects and all work fine. Give more information. Try to download a project from https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Looks like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932989/error-migrating-spring-boot-1-5-10-to-2-0-6

Answer (score 0):

For gradle project in gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file change distributionUrl variable to:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-bin.zip

If it is don't helps download project from https://start.spring.io/ and do the same.

If you use maven, just download maven project from https://start.spring.io/ . It should work fine.